# Display topmenu in left side in magento.?

Tags: xml, layout, magento, php

I have choose one column page for my site in magento. Now i want to show topmenu in left side. Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly,this is how navigation can be created.But i wonder how do you display navigation when you set one column layout.
Create a template file(left_nav.phtml) in `/your_theme/template/catalog/navigation/`

```
<div class="block block-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
         <h2><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></h2>
    </div>
   <div class="block-content">
        <ul id="nav_vert">
        <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
            <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If local.xml does not exist,create it `/you_theme/layout/` and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default> 
          <reference name="header">
               <remove name="top.menu"/>
          </reference>  
          <reference name="left">
               <block type="catalog/navigation" name="left_nav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/> 
          <reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi sir... As I am having the same requirement, I have used this code. But it is llist all the categories and sub categories at once.. It is not using the 'js' also.. So how can I make it work with my 'js' as I required? FYI I am using 2column left page....

Answer (score 3):

Use this module:-

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Rico+Neitzel/extension/763/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes

> With this extension you're able to
>   design you own vertical category
>   navigation with subcategories and
>   product count display.

It's Free as well.